# Не могу установить vk-io

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Вот что происходит, когда я пытаюсь установить `vk-io`:

```
npm ERR! code ENOSELF
npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "vk-io" under a package
npm ERR! also called "vk-io". Did you name your project the same
npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For more information, see:
npm ERR!     <https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#limitations-of-npms-install-algorithm>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\w10-64\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-10T15_13_57_576Z-debug.log
```

Comment: написано что папка названа идентично пакету

Answer (score 1):

Ну написано же:

> Did you name your project the same as the dependency you're installing?

Переименуй проект.